# Node js catch headers and do something with it

Tags: node.js

Hi I'm new to Node js and I'm currently working on a simple app, but I've stumbled upon a problem when I try to make a request to get a certain header from the response. The problem is that whenever I start the request it makes infinite calls and my server crashes.

Here is my code

```
var request  = require('request'),
    url = require('url');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
    req.pathName = req.pathName || url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    var path = '';

    if(req.pathName !== '/content/style.css') {
        path = req.pathName;
    }

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:7357' + path,
        method: 'HEAD'
    }

    request(options,function(err, response) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if(response.headers.statusheader && response.headers.statusheader === 'Full') {
                console.log('do something');
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've set up a header like that in my **homepage.js** file

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
    req.pathName = req.pathName || url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if(req.pathName === '/') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'StatusHeader': 'Full'
            });
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is how I call every modules

```
var favicon = require('./favicon'),
    homepage = require('./homepage'),
    upload = require('./upload'),
    gallery = require('./gallery'),
    details = require('./details'),
    catch_header = require('./catch_header'),
    normal = require('./normal');

module.exports = [favicon, catch_header, homepage, upload, gallery, details, normal];

var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    handlers = require('./handlers/main');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        for(var handler of handlers) {
            var proceed = handler(req, res);

            if(!proceed) {
                break;
            }
        }
    })
    .listen(7357);
```

So my question is what is the workaround for this issue, how can I prevent my server from crashing

Comment: Why are you using request() to call your webserver here?  It seems unnecessary...?

Comment: I've tried with http.request as well the result is the same

Comment: What I mean, is that I can't think of any reason why you would ever want to do any sort of http request from this section in the code... or any section for that matter.

Comment: How can I get the headers then ? I have to create a piece of code that catches the headers and if that particular header is being catch then do something after that

Comment: Couldn't you put an if statement after your "proceed = handler" code in the last section that just checks the response header to see if it's present, then call some other code?

Comment: my assignment is to make it a separate file, the same way I have a normal.js that controls the static files, I need to make one that takes the header and does something afterwards